# ActionScript PrintJob.send not working in Electron

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, printing, electron, actionscript

Adobe Flash - ActionScript `PrintJob.send` method does not work in Electron. The screen just flashes without showing any Print Dialog.

Is there any alternative to show the Print Dialog in ActionScript?

Comment: Did you have any progress in this problem?